# Reversing the stacking order of live text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typography, typesetting

I'm working on a graphic where I want to overlap the type. I created a text box, typed out a big old heavy font. Alternated Letter colors, put a stroke on the whole thing then pulled in the kerning like crazy. It is overlapping, but my question is can I  switch the overlap order so instead of the first letter being in the back it is in the front? I know that this is possible when you are using the blend tool but wanted to know if anyone knew how to do this using live text.

I know that I can outline it and do this manually, but I wanted to see if I could do it with live text.

[image]

Comment: Just have each letter on it's own. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible with a bit of trickery...

Set the Character Rotation of the text to 180 degrees (so each character is upside-down)...

[image]

Then rotate the whole text object 180 degrees to correct the character orientation (this will switch the stacking order in the process)...

[image]

Of course your text is now written backwards so you'll need to retype it backwards (the following image actually says "PALREVO"), but it's still live type.

[image]

*(...All of that said, this is just an awkward hack and there's no real way to control the stacking order of type in a single text object. It'd probably be easier to just outline your type or use separate text objects.)*

Answer (score 0):

To use live type, you would need *each glyph* to be a separate type object. (In which case, you may as well create outlines.)

You *can't* control the "stacking" in one single live type string.